# How to prevent cpan fron using proxy?

Tags: perl, cpan

My knowledge of perl is limited to running commands. I have managed to come up with a shell script to output the gav of a pom.xml, using xpath as follows:

```
 xpath pom.xml  '//project/artifactId/text()'
```

On a new machine right now, this does not work because I do not have the XPath.pm installed:

```
 Can't locate XML/XPath.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14 /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/5.14 .)
```

I seem to remember installing XPath using cpan so I tried the following command, blindly:

```
cpan XPath
```

This is probably not the correct command to use, but I think that is unrelated to the issue I am facing. The command gives following error:

```
Going to read '/home/****/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Mon, 25 Aug 2014 00:41:02 GMT
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
HTTP::Tiny failed with an internal error: Could not connect to 'proxy:8080': IO::Socket::INET: Bad hostname 'proxy' at /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/HTTP/Tiny.pm line 139

Proxy authentication needed!
 (Note: to permanently configure username and password run
   o conf proxy_user your_username
   o conf proxy_pass your_password
     )
Username:    C-c C-c
```

Why is `HTTP::Tiny` looking for host proxy? We do have a corporate proxy with hostname proxy but that is needed only when I am on corporate network or VPN, neither of which is case right now.

How do I convince `HTTP::Tiny` to connect directly to internet? I do not have an envvar named `http_proxy` or `HTTP_PROXY` set.

Comment: I did not know to check settings, but now I saw it was wrong. I was able to change it and now it has gone past the error. If you convert your comment to question, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the environment variable is used, `cpan` first checks its configuration.

To view: `o conf http_proxy`
To clear: `o conf http_proxy ''`

Don't forget to use `o conf commit` to make the change permanent.

Answer (score 1):

CPAN uses HTTP:Tiny to download info about the module you are asking for.  It is lightweight so it runs fast.

Either CPAN has not been configured, or the cpan found on your path is configured to use the proxy.  Determine the location of the CPAN program you are executing and proceed from there.

Answer (score 1):

This msg `Can't locate XML/XPath.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14 /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/lib/perl5/5.14 .)` shows that module is not installed.
If you are on windows and using a proxy setting. You can use these commands to install module from ppm or cpan. Open a command prompt and run these commands :

```
set http_proxy=http://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:yyyy (xxx is your system proxy and yyyy is port)
set http_proxy_user=username (login username)
set http_proxy_pass=password (login password)
```

To install a module from cpan type:

```
cpan install modulename
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you have set http_proxy variable to direct IP, Instead, put http_proxy=http://ipaddress , then it will work